# How to properly read dates from a csv / excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have a CSV file that needs to be opened in excel. I want to read an entire row at a time into my program and store it in some kind of list or array. In past projects I have used:

```
DateTime[] dates = xlworksheet.get_Range("B7", "B"+xlWorksheet.Rows.Count);
```

This is giving me the error: "Cannot convert type 'object[*,*]' to 'System.DateTime[]'". This makes sense but I don't know how to store the entire column other wise. **How do I read an entire column from an excel worksheet into a list/array in my program?**

Comment: Can you just store the data, then convert it one at a time and _then_ put it in your DateTime array?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the cell block I am looking at isn't empty, I tried this before and it was working right, it would be so much nicer if I didnt need to manually loop through individually, but if it is all I can do then I will need to.

Comment: I have run into the same situation a bunch of times in the last month or so, I usually just end up implementing a foreach loop. Generally doesn't add too many lines and still very readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using .NET 3.5 or higher.  Add a using System.Linq;

```
DateTime[] dates = xlworksheet.get_Range("B7", "B"+xlWorksheet.Rows.Count).Cast<DateTime>().ToArray();
```

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 or higher however this doesn't work. But it may help me when i try the previously suggested idea which was to iterate one line at a time...